# Turn Screen Upside Down Horizontal

Tags: lock-screens, screen

I need to turn my android phone horizontal, but have the "up" side be the side that is closer to the ground. How does one do this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean 180° rotation - lots of screen rotation apps, like [Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate), can be set up to do that.

The bonus point of the one I linked to is that, after setting up properly, it will seamlessly integrate with the built-in rotation switch of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

This app does exactly what you are asking for
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pranavpandey.rotation

StackExchange will not approve my answer unless I add more information, so here's a 1:1 citation of what the app author writes:

```
Rotation is a tool to manage the device orientation. It offers all the modes that Android supports and can be configured according to the apps or various events like call, lock, headset, charging and dock. Let's give it a try to explore its other features.

FEATURES

Orientations
• Auto-rotate on • Auto-rotate off
• Forced auto-rotate • Forced portrait • Forced landscape
• Reverse portrait • Reverse landscape • Sensor portrait • Sensor landscape
• Forced full sensor • Lock Current – Lock current orientation

Conditions
• Call orientation • Lock orientation • Headset orientation
• Charging orientation • Dock orientation • App orientation
• Events priority - Customizable events preference in case of two or more events occur simultaneously.

On demand
# Change orientation of the foreground app or events with a fully customizable floating head (or notification or tile) available on the top of supported tasks.

Themes
• A dynamic theme engine with background-aware functionality to avoid any visibility issues.

Others
• Start on boot • Notification • Vibration and more.
• Widgets, shortcuts and notification tiles to perform various operations.
# Rotation extension to automate over 40 actions via Locale / Tasker plugin.

Support
• Quick setup to configure major features at once.
• Dedicated support section to troubleshoot general issues.
# Perform backup and restore operations to save and load the app settings.

Features marked with # are paid and Rotation Key is required to use them.

LANGUAGES
English, Deutsch, Español, Indonesia, Italiano, Português, Русский, Türkçe, 中文 (简体), 中文 (繁體)

PERMISSIONS
Internet access – To display ads in free version.
Retrieve running apps – To detect foreground app.
Usage statistics (Android 5.0+) – To detect foreground app.
Modify system settings – To change display orientation settings.
Draw over other apps – To change foreground orientation.
Read device state and identity – To change the phone call orientation.
Run at startup – To start service when device boots up.
Control vibration – To vibrate device when orientation changes.
Modify USB storage (Android 4.3 and below) – To create and restore backup.

ACCESSIBILITY
It uses an accessibility service to provide a better experience and to force the lock screen orientation on Android 8.0+ devices. It will not access window content or any other sensitive data.
Rotation > Conditions > Events > Accessibility.

------------------------------

- Buy Rotation Key for more features and to support the development.
- In case of bugs/issues, please contact me via email before making any review.
- Some apps might not work properly when forced to work in certain orientations. Use Auto-rotate on/off from conditions to use system settings for those apps.
- Reverse portrait is disabled on some Xiaomi (MIUI) devices with default launcher. Please try any other launcher (home screen) to make it work.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).